# C# docking control library

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, controls, docking

I'm looking for a docking control library for C# WinForms that works in NET 2.0, is freeware, doesn't use any P/Invokes (so that it's compatible with Mono) and isn't buggy. [WeifenLuo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) would have been the best option here, but because it uses a ton of P/Invokes, I will never be able to get my software to be cross-platform.

So any good suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get WeifenLuo's docking library control (DockPanel Suite) working on Mono, at the cost of some features.

If anyone is interested, please read [this.](http://www.lextm.com/2010/05/dockpanel-suite-tip-4-we-could-go-mono.html)

Comment: Updated: http://www.lextm.com/2012/05/a-call-to-the-community-dockpanel-suite-history-and-future-2/ DPS now has a new home http://dockpanelsuite.com.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/), but I can't say whether it uses P/Invoke.

Comment: SharpDevelop old releases use WinForms and DockPanel Suite in fact. So it uses P/Invoke. Latest SharpDevelop uses WPF and AvalonDock, which is not cross platform/Mono friendly either.